# Insert where not exists Violation of PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql

I'm having troubles with an Insert where not exists and I'm not sure if a MERGE statement would be more efficient or what's wrong with my statement.

I have en existing View and need to insert the new records of this View into a Table.

The Table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ser_number_all]
     (Serialnumber nvarchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
     TypeName nvarchar(max),
     Date datetime,
     Parent_Serialnumber nvarchar(100),
     JobNumber nvarchar(30),
     ProductNode hierarchyid,
         );
```

The Insert statement looks like this:

```
insert into [dbo].[ser_number_all]
  ( Serialnumber
  , TypeName
  , Date
  , Parent_Serialnumber
  , JobNumber
  , ProductNode)
  select    Serialnumber
          , TypeName
          , Date
          , Parent_Serialnumber
          , JobNumber
          , ProductNode
  from dbo.Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as ser_number_all
where not exists (select 1
                  from Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as hv
                  where hv. Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Serialnumber
                  and hv. TypeName = ser_number_all.TypeName
                  and hv. Date = ser_number_all.Date
                  and hv. Parent_Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Parent_Serialnumber
                  and hv. JobNumber = ser_number_all.JobNumber
                  and hv. ProductNode = ser_number_all.ProductNode);
```

As long the View has not any new records, it looks ok and I'm not getting any error, the output is 0 records as it should be.

When I add a new record to the origin table and the view has 1 record more, I'm always getting this error:

```
    Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ser_numb__F2753A12C4ABA976'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ser_number_all'. The duplicate key value is (.x3666AB05).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I don't get it why it will insert a duplicate value in the primary key column because in my WHERE clause I can't see any mistake.

I have also tried with IS NULL instead = ser_number_all.TypeName and for all other columns where it could have a NULL value, but still the same.

Again, I'm coming from Oracle and it looks like I have to learn many diversities with MS SQL compared to Oracle.

Appreciate any suggestion :-)
Thx

EDIT:

Here the code of the View:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers]
AS
WITH ProductList
AS
(
SELECT  p.Serialnumber, 
p.Type_Id,
p.Parent_Serialnumber, 
p.ActiveJob_Jobnumber as JobNumber,
N'/' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.Serialnumber)) + N'/' AS ProductNode_AsChar
FROM Products AS p
WHERE p.Parent_Serialnumber IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT  p.Serialnumber, 
p.Type_Id, 
p.Parent_Serialnumber, 
JobNumber,
pl.ProductNode_AsChar + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.Serialnumber)) + N'/'
FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN ProductList AS pl ON p.Parent_Serialnumber = pl.Serialnumber
)
SELECT  Serialnumber,
pt.Name as TypeName,
Parent_Serialnumber,
JobNumber,
CONVERT(HIERARCHYID, ProductNode_AsChar) AS ProductNode
FROM ProductList as pl
INNER JOIN ProductTypes as pt on pl.Type_Id = pt.Id;
```

Comment: you are inserting into `[dbo].[ser_number_all]` and you are correlating `Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers `

Comment: Yes, Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers is the View where we get the data and all new records should be inserted into the table ser_number_all.

Comment: what i am saying is try correlating with the view

Comment: Could you please post the schema for the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TheGameiswar

Sorry, now I got it what you meant ;-) Stupid me...

Here the solution which works now with correctly correlating:

```
    insert into [dbo].[ser_number_all]
  ( Serialnumber
  , TypeName
  , Date
  , Parent_Serialnumber
  , JobNumber
  , ProductNode)
  select    Serialnumber
          , TypeName
          , Date
          , Parent_Serialnumber
          , JobNumber
          , ProductNode
  from dbo.Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as hv
where not exists (select 1
                  from ser_number_all as sna
                  where hv. Serialnumber = sna.Serialnumber);
```

Thank you all for your time and guiding me to the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

The primary key for table [ser_number_all] is [Serialnumber].
So your

```
Where Not Exists ()
```

statement should only contain:

```
Where Not Exists ( Select Top 1 S.[Serialnumber] From [dbo].[ser_number_all] As S Where S.[Serialnumber] = <The Value you are trying to insert for Serial Number>)
```

This way, you are preventing the insertion of duplicate records that will violate your Primary Key.